# How to edit existing map geometry in mappable-maps?

Tags: javascript, mappable

How can i edit geometry in mappable?

Is it possible to edit the geometry (polygons, lines) that have already been added to the map using `map.addChild(myGeometry)`?
You can permanently delete irrelevant geometry using `map.removeChild(myGeometry)` and recreate it again with updated coordinates, but this is very inefficient.

Comment: Are you talking about some kind of library? If so, please clearly state it and if it has SO Tag - add it